# Interaction with array results in a segfault

Tags: arrays, assembly, input, x86, nasm

I'm trying to implement a simple addition calculator, but I'm not able to store the input in my array. I'm trying to read char by char because I want to use it later to implement a backend for my B compiler (which has the getchar function that reads char by char from stdin). My code is the fallowing:

```
segment .data
    numb db  0, 0, 0, 0
    indx db  0
    char db  '0'
    newl db  0ah

    msg1 db  'enter a number: '
    len1 equ $ - msg1

segment .text
global _start                       ; defines the entry point

print:                              ; push msg; push len
    pop   eax                       ; removes caller address from stack
    pop   edx                       ; gets length
    pop   ecx                       ; gets msg
    push  eax                       ; pushes CA to stack again

    mov   ebx ,   01h               ; tells that it's an output call
    mov   eax ,   04h               ; system call (write)
    int   80h                       ; calls it
    ret

getc:                               ; push add; push len
    pop   eax                       ; removes caller address from stack
    pop   ecx                       ; gets ouput addrress
    push  eax                       ; pushes CA to stack again

    mov   edx ,   01h
    mov   ebx ,   00h               ; tells that it's an input call
    mov   eax ,   03h               ; system call (read)
    int   80h                       ; calls it
    ret

exit:
    mov   ebx ,   0                 ; sets exit code
    mov   eax ,   01h               ; system call (exit)
    int   80h                       ; calls it

_start:
    push  msg1
    push  len1
    call  print

    read:
    push  char
    call  getc

    mov   eax ,   numb
    add   eax ,   indx
    mov  [eax],   dword char

    inc           byte [indx]

    mov   eax ,   char
    cmp   eax ,   newl
    jne   read

    jmp   exit                      ; exits program
```

for now I'm just trying to store the input, because I got segfaults from the complete code, so I started stripping off code until I found the error cause.

Comment: `add   eax ,   indx` - you're adding two addresses together, not zero-extending the byte value stored there.  Use a debugger to single-step, and remember the difference between `indx` and `[indx]`.  You'll need a `movzx` load into another reg since `db` is narrower than a pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I got it but I can't check because I received another problem (cmp/jne not working as expected), should I edit the post or open another question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to insert the newline in the array, so start with checking for the newline:

```
read:
    push  char
    call  getc
    mov   al, [char]
    cmp   al, 10
    je    done
```

Then load the byte-sized index in an address register, remembering that `AL` already contains the datum, so pick another register than `EAX`. Also, instead of adding the array address *numb* and the index *indx* yourself, let the CPU do that for your with an addressing mode that has a displacement component (`[numb + ebx]`):

```
    movzx ebx, byte [indx]
    mov   [numb + ebx], al
    inc   byte [indx]
    jmp   read
done:
    jmp   exit
```

There's also the possibility to define the index *indx* as a dword with `indx dd 0`. Then the code becomes:

```
read:
    push  char
    call  getc
    mov   al, [char]
    cmp   al, 10
    je    done
    mov   ebx, [indx]
    mov   [numb + ebx], al
    inc   dword [indx]
    jmp   read
done:
    jmp   exit
```

The lesson here is that NASM is different from MASM in how you address memory:

### MASM

```
mov eax, offset MyVar    ; Load address of MyVar
mov eax, MyVar           ; Load value stored in MyVar
```

### NASM

```
mov eax, MyVar           ; Load address of MyVar
mov eax, [MyVar]         ; Load value stored in MyVar
```

Comment: It worked, but first I tried to assemble without defining index as double word. This segfaulted, but then I fixed it and worked. Why did this happen?

Comment: @mateus.md Without seeing your code I can only guess. One way to segfault is keeping *indx* a byte, but using the last code snippet in my answer. NASM does not care about sizes (too much) and will happily assembly `mov ebx, [indx]` resulting in an offset that is too big for the .data segment.